# Excel 2013 Data Validation List no longer works in my workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, data-validation

I am using Microsoft Office Professional 2013 with Excel 2013 on a Window 7 Enterprise Laptop.

I have run into a problem that I cannot correct.  I have a worksheet that I have been tracking data in since January 14. One of my column values is a data validation list which points to a tab labeled controls.  All of a sudden when I click on the cell in the row the drop down control does no work. If I try to type a value not defined where the list is located I get an error message telling me I am attempting to add a value not in the list.   I gather the data and enter it into the workbook on the appropriate months tab. Once the weeks data is compiled I save it as new document adding v1, v2, v3 etc. depending what week of the month.  Version 4 works, but the new Version 5 does not.  Does anyone have any idea why this maybe happening?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, Paste Special option can wipe the Data Validation. Did you try any Paste Special option in the sheet.

Or it can be some corruption would made the Data Validation to not work. Please try Repair the problematic excel sheet and check the outcome.

a) In Excel, choose File | Open
b) Select the file with the missing data validation arrows
c) On the Open button, click the arrow
d) Click Open and Repair
e) When prompted, click Repair

Hope this helps.